# unable to load javascript from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension. My content-script is a javascript class with set of functions.

```
myClass = class {
 constructor() {
   console.log('Script loaded');
  }

 get one() {}
 get two() {}
 get three() {}

}

obj = new myClass();
```

When I click on my chrome extension, the idea is to load above javascript and I should be able to call all the methods using obj.   While I am getting 'Script loaded' message from the constructor in the console, when I try to call the methods using obj, I am getting below error.

```
obj is not defined.
```

If I copy-paste the entire content script in the console and try yo call the class methods using obj, it's working without any issues. what am I doing wrong here?

Manifest.json

```
    {
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name":"ext1",
    "description":"some desc",
    "version":"1.0.1",
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
     },

     "permissions":[
     "contextMenus",
     "activeTab"
     ]

   }
```

background.js

```
var contextMenus = {};

  contextMenus.ext1 =
  chrome.contextMenus.create(
    { "title": "some title" },
    function () {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);

        }
    }
  );

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(contextMenuHandler);

function contextMenuHandler(info, tab) {
 if (info.menuItemId === contextMenus.ext1) {
  
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'js/ext1.js'
    });
  

 }
}
```

Comment: use the `alert` method to check if the script is actually loaded or not

Comment: it did load, that is when i got the console.log message provided in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with context. Can you try to assign `obj` and `myClass` to block scope variables `let` or `const`. Example:

```
const myClass = class {
 constructor() {
   console.log('Script loaded');
  }

 get one() {}
 get two() {}
 get three() {}

}

const obj = new myClass();
```

Comment: its not working still.